# subprocess sometimes sends returns empty

Tags: windows, python-3.x, subprocess, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have the following class that is used to run a third party command line tool which I have no control over.

I run this ina `Qthread` in a `PyQt` Gui.

I turn the `gui` into an `EXE` using `Pyinstaller`

Problems are more prevalent when it is an `EXE`

```
class CLI_Interface:

    def process_f(self, command, bsize=4096):

        self.kill_process(CLI_TOOL)

        startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        startupinfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE

        p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
                  startupinfo=startupinfo, bufsize=bsize, universal_newlines=True) 
        try:
             out, err = p.communicate(timeout=120)            
        except TimeoutExpired:
            p.kill()            
            out, err = p.communicate()
        return out.split(), err.split()


    def kill_process(self, proc):
        # Check process is running, Kill it if it is,
        #  return False if not.
        # uses its own popen for Stderr >> stdout
        #  If we use the self.process_f method, it will create an infinite loop

        startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        startupinfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
        try:
            kill_proc = Popen("TaskKill /IM {} /T /F".format(proc), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
                              startupinfo=startupinfo, universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0]
            if 'ERROR' not in kill_proc.split():
                return True  # Process Killed
            else:
                self.kill_process(proc)
        except Exception as e:
            return False


    def download_data(self, code):
        """ download data from the device based on a 5 digit code """

        command = '"{}" -l {},{} {}'.format(CLI_TOOL_PATH,
                                            code[0], code[2], code[1]) 
        try:
            p = self.process_f(command)
            proc, err = p[0], p[1]   
            try:
                if err[-2] == '-p':
                    return False
                return True
            except IndexError:
                if not proc:
                    return False # This means there is no data but the file is still saved!!
                pass
            return True            
        except Exception as e:
            return False

    def ....
    def ....
    def ....
```

Thread:

```
class GetDataThread(QThread):

    taskFinished = pyqtSignal()
    notConnected = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, f, parent=None):
        super(GetDataThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.f = f

    def run(self):        

        is_dongle_connected()

        DD = cli.download_data(self.f)

        if not DD:
            self.notConnected.emit()
        else:
            self.taskFinished.emit()
```

I either get a `done!` or `error`  - This is normal when running from the command line.

Sometimes I get an `empty list` returned and I put this back into a recursive loop after killing the program.

However, it does not seem to restart properly and the problem continues - it gets stuck in a loop of nothing!.

Meanwhile, the csv files the cli tool produces are created as normal yet I have no data from `stdout / stderr`

Looking at processes the `conhost` and the `cli` tool are destroyed no problem.

The gui will continue to fail (until I unplug and plug in the dongle and / or restart the program / computer.

When I open the CLI and run the same command, it works fine or throws an error (which I catch in the program no problem)

I have tried setting a buffer as some files generated can reach `2.4mb`

I tried setting a higher timeout to allow for it to finish.

There does not seem to be a correlation with file size though and it can get stuck at any size.

The flow is like so:

Gui >> CLI >> Dongle >> Sensor

Running on Windows 10

How can I make the connection more solid or debug what processes might still be lingering around and stopping this?

Is it blocking?

Is it a pipe buffer overflow? - If so How do I determine the correct `bufsize`?

Is it something to do with PyQt and Python Subprocess or Pyinstaller?

Would it be better to use `QProcess` instead of `Subprocess`?

Thanks in advance!